# Longtable in landscape environment

Tags: longtable, landscape

I need to have a long table with 7 columns so I chose the landscape format. Everything is working just fine except the text of the last column which is not sitting in the right place. I can't understand why the text is not respecting the margins of the page (the text that I wrote after the table is). In the picture, there's an example of this.

Here are a few lines of the code to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}
{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.055\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.06\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.22\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.04\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.15\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.05\linewidth}>
{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{0.3\linewidth}}
\caption{EEG table} \\
\label{tab:EEG}
\textbf{} & \textbf{Cohort} & \textbf{MI Task} & \textbf{NC} &
\textbf{Network Nodes} & \textbf{Metrics} & \textbf{Main Findings} 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\\
 \textbf{} & \textbf{Cohort} & \textbf{MI Task} & \textbf{NC} 
& \textbf{Network Nodes} & \textbf{Metrics} & \textbf{Main Findings}\\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{1.089\linewidth}}
{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.714,0.714,0.714}}\textbf{Effective Connectivity}}   
\\
\hline 

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.871,0.871,0.871} Vukelić, Mathias et al. (2014)                 & 16 HS                                                                            & kinesthetic imagination of opening the right hand; each trial consisted of a preparation (2s), MI (6s), and rest (8s) phase                                                                                                                                                                                                      & 32                                                                      & 24 electrodes as nodes                                                                                                                                                                                   & PSI                                                  & activation of an ipsilateral sensorimotor–parietal EC network is an indicator of a low ability for regional sensorimotor $\beta$-modulation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\
Yi, Weibo et al. (2014)                                                          & 10 HS                                                                            & imagine left hand, right hand, feet, both hands and hand combined with foot movements; each trial consisted of a preparation cue (1s), MI (4s) and rest (1s) phase                                                                                                                                                               & 64                                                                      & 21 electrodes as nodes                                                                                                                                                                                   & \textcolor{red}{PLV}, SDTF       & findings imply that there exist apparent intrinsic distinctions of neural mechanism between simple and compound limb MI, which presents a more complex EC network and may involve a more complex cognitive process during information processing                                                                                                                                                           \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.871,0.871,0.871} Liang, Shuang et al. (2016)                    & 9 HS                                                                             & imagination of movement of the left hand, right hand, both feet and tongue; each trial consisted of a cue (1.25s), MI (3s, no feedback was provided) and rest (1.5s) phase                                                                                                                                                       & 22                                                                      & 9 electrodes used as nodes                                                                                                                                                                               & PDC                                                  & significant EC exists in the bilateral hemisphere during the tasks, regardless of the left or right-hand MI tasks. Furthermore, the out-in rate results of the information flow reveal the existence of contralateral lateralisation; \textcolor{red}{using PDC to compute EC provides efficient features for the detection of MI tasks and has great potential to be applied in BCIs}  

\end{longtable}

\textbf{Abbreviations:}
\textbf{ADTF} Adaptive Directed Transfer Function,
\textbf{BCI} Brain Computer Interface,
\textbf{CCorr} Cross Correlation,
\textbf{CMA} Cingulate Motor Areas,
\textbf{Coh} Coherence,
\textbf{Corr} Correlation,
\textbf{DCM} Dynamic Causal Modelling


\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table. It should have at least four rows, that we can see how are colored.

Comment: @Zarko not sure if I understand but I edited the code fragment. This is part of a tex file that I use as input in my main tex file. The following lines of the table are the first head and the head which appears on the next pages and then there are just lines with the content of the table (I used a generator that colours each row)

Comment: {We need complete document, which start with  `\documentclass ...` and end with `\end{document}` which reproduce your problem. With your first code fragment is not possible to reproduce shower result, the second fragment is not compilable, So it is not clear what is your problem.

Comment: @Zarko I'm using a personalised document class for my thesis so it will be hard to reproduce but the class is based on the report.cls. The packages for the table are `\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}`

Comment: @Zarko I just started a new document with `\documentclass{report}` and then the `\begin{document}` and the piece of code that I have in my question and the problem remains

Comment: so make an example that shows the problem, don't make everyone guess how to construct an example

Comment: your table is .875\linewidth+ 14\tabcolsep wide, which is probably  .875\linewidth+84pt  that may or may not be wider than line width depending on settings you have not shown.  but `\multicolumn{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{1.089\linewidth}}` is _definitely_ more than `\linewidth` and will force the table to be over-wide.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just edited the code example and is now reproducible, thanks for the suggestion. I adjusted that 1.089\linewidth because I was not able to change the width of the last column to fit

Comment: well with such an entry the table will always be over sized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of `longtblr` of `tabularray` package instead of `longtalble`, you can write shorter code which gives better formatted table. Using `X` columns the table width is equal to `\linewidth` (= `\textheight`) and also can be determined ratio between column widths except for the second and fourth column, at which is preserved natural width determined with cells contents. The second and the last column have justified text, which to my opinion gives better looks of table.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \footnotesize
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {EEG table},
  label = {tab:EEG}
                ]{colsep=4pt,
                  colspec = {X[0.5,l,m] Q[c,m]
                             X[1.8,j,m] Q[c,m] X[0.7,l,m] X[0.3,c,m]
                             X[2.2,j,m]
                            },
                  cell{2}{1} = {c=7}{c},
                  row{1,2} = {c, font=\bfseries},
                  row{2}   = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!45},
                  row{odd[3]} = {bg=gray!15},
                  rowhead  = 1}
    \toprule
    &   Cohort  
        &   MI Task 
            &   NC  
                &   Network Nodes   
                    &   Met\-rics 
                        &   Main Findings   \\
    \midrule
Effective Connectivity
    &   &   &   &   &   &                   \\
Vukelić, Mathias et al. (2014)                 
    &   16 HS   
        &   kinesthetic imagination of opening the right hand; each trial consisted of a preparation (2s), MI (6s), and rest (8s) phase
            &   32
                &   24 electrodes as nodes
                    &   PSI
                        &   activation of an ipsilateral sensorimotor–parietal EC network is an indicator of a low ability for regional sensorimotor $\beta$-modulation
                        \\
Yi, Weibo et al. (2014)
    &   10 HS 
        &   imagine left hand, right hand, feet, both hands and hand combined with foot movements; each trial consisted of a preparation cue (1s), MI (4s) and rest (1s) phase
            &   64
                &   21 electrodes as nodes
                    & \textcolor{red}{PLV}, SDTF
                        &   findings imply that there exist apparent intrinsic distinctions of neural mechanism between simple and compound limb MI, which presents a more complex EC network and may involve a more complex cognitive process during information processing                                                                                                                                                           \\
Liang, Shuang et al. (2016)                    
    &   9 HS                                                                             
        &   imagination of movement of the left hand, right hand, both feet and tongue; each trial consisted of a cue (1.25s), MI (3s, no feedback was provided) and rest (1.5s) phase                                                                                                                                                     
            &   22
                &   9 electrodes used as nodes
                    &   PDC
                        &   significant EC exists in the bilateral hemisphere during the tasks, regardless of the left or right-hand MI tasks. Furthermore, the out-in rate results of the information flow reveal the existence of contralateral lateralisation; \textcolor{red}{using PDC to compute EC provides efficient features for the detection of MI tasks and has great potential to be applied in BCIs}
                        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\textbf{Abbreviations:}
\textbf{ADTF} Adaptive Directed Transfer Function,
\textbf{BCI} Brain Computer Interface,
\textbf{CCorr} Cross Correlation,
\textbf{CMA} Cingulate Motor Areas,
\textbf{Coh} Coherence,
\textbf{Corr} Correlation,
\textbf{DCM} Dynamic Causal Modelling
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does look better! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You wer forcing the table to be wider than the text block with an explicit `1.089\linewidth` in a multicolumn, and the sum of the column widths and `\tabcolsep` spacing was more than `\linewidth`, I reduced `\tabcolsep` here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\noindent X\dotfill X

\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{4.9pt}
\begin{longtable}
{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.055\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.06\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.22\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.04\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.15\linewidth}>
{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.05\linewidth}>
{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{0.3\linewidth}}
\caption{EEG table} \\
\label{tab:EEG}
\textbf{} & \textbf{Cohort} & \textbf{MI Task} & \textbf{NC} &
\textbf{Network Nodes} & \textbf{Metrics} & \textbf{Main Findings} 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\\
 \textbf{} & \textbf{Cohort} & \textbf{MI Task} & \textbf{NC} 
& \textbf{Network Nodes} & \textbf{Metrics} & \textbf{Main Findings}\\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}
{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.714,0.714,0.714}}\textbf{Effective Connectivity}}   
\\
\hline 

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.871,0.871,0.871} Vukelić, Mathias et al. (2014)                 & 16 HS                                                                            & kinesthetic imagination of opening the right hand; each trial consisted of a preparation (2s), MI (6s), and rest (8s) phase                                                                                                                                                                                                      & 32                                                                      & 24 electrodes as nodes                                                                                                                                                                                   & PSI                                                  & activation of an ipsilateral sensorimotor–parietal EC network is an indicator of a low ability for regional sensorimotor $\beta$-modulation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\
Yi, Weibo et al. (2014)                                                          & 10 HS                                                                            & imagine left hand, right hand, feet, both hands and hand combined with foot movements; each trial consisted of a preparation cue (1s), MI (4s) and rest (1s) phase                                                                                                                                                               & 64                                                                      & 21 electrodes as nodes                                                                                                                                                                                   & \textcolor{red}{PLV}, SDTF       & findings imply that there exist apparent intrinsic distinctions of neural mechanism between simple and compound limb MI, which presents a more complex EC network and may involve a more complex cognitive process during information processing                                                                                                                                                           \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.871,0.871,0.871} Liang, Shuang et al. (2016)                    & 9 HS                                                                             & imagination of movement of the left hand, right hand, both feet and tongue; each trial consisted of a cue (1.25s), MI (3s, no feedback was provided) and rest (1.5s) phase                                                                                                                                                       & 22                                                                      & 9 electrodes used as nodes                                                                                                                                                                               & PDC                                                  & significant EC exists in the bilateral hemisphere during the tasks, regardless of the left or right-hand MI tasks. Furthermore, the out-in rate results of the information flow reveal the existence of contralateral lateralisation; \textcolor{red}{using PDC to compute EC provides efficient features for the detection of MI tasks and has great potential to be applied in BCIs}  

\end{longtable}

\textbf{Abbreviations:}
\textbf{ADTF} Adaptive Directed Transfer Function,
\textbf{BCI} Brain Computer Interface,
\textbf{CCorr} Cross Correlation,
\textbf{CMA} Cingulate Motor Areas,
\textbf{Coh} Coherence,
\textbf{Corr} Correlation,
\textbf{DCM} Dynamic Causal Modelling


\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied your settings but I would never use `\centering` for those long text entries centred text is very hard to read, use `\raggedright`.

Comment: Thank you so much and also for your suggestion!